# Why are there gaps between bibliographic entries?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, vertical-spacing

the bibliography code is

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,refs}
```

[It is OK on the 1st page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXXf0.png)

[But why are there gaps on the 2nd page?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSBL5.png)

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: document class is \documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}

Comment: What happens if you run `\raggedbottom` in the preamble?

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. Good luck with your project!